# Laravel Middleware is Not Being Called When Access the Routes

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

I have created a Middleware via `php artisan make: middleware AdminCheck`

Registered it in *kernal.php*

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminCheck::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
     //default middlewares.....
];
```

In web.php this is how I'm using it for all my routes

```
Route::prefix('/app')->middleware('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/create_tag', 'AdminController@addTag');
    Route::get('/get_tags', 'AdminController@getTag');
    Route::post('/edit_tag', 'AdminController@editTag');
});
```

Here is my The Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminCheck
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    Log::info("Middleware Reached");
    dd("Middleware Reached");
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        //l redirect to login 
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
 }
```

The middleware is working since the routes are still accessed even without login and there's nothing in the log and its not die dumping either

Comment: are your routes cached? do `php artisan about` if so, clear your route cache and try again

Comment: Another thing, if you are going to be using auth, you should load your admin middleware after auth not before

Comment: @kgg thanks been doing php artisan optimize  but you suggestion solved it

Comment: Glad it worked, I have added an answer to the question to get future readers the answer to similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

For similar issues in the future, kindly check your cache, you can do so by doing

```
php artisan about
```

To clear your cache you can do:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

It will list what is cached, if you are going to be making any changes to route/config/views you should clear the cache and cache again.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear ` perform all of this